# How many hit points does a sieged city have remaining?

Tags: civilization-5

I am attacking a city and would like to know how many hitpoints it has remaining. I have tried hovering over the hex and city plaque.

All you can see from the screenshot is that the city is in the red with hitpoints.

I know you could approximate this. However, when a city is in the red of a 100HP city. There could be as much as 15 HP remaining. The scale of the red bar makes it difficult to guess. So my question stands where I am not looking for `just guess it answers`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cities have different strength (as seen in in the number next to the shield icon), but they all have the same number of hit points, i.e. 25 (used to be 20, this changed in 1.0.1.135).

So yes, you have to guess (which sucks), but it's always against the same number of base hit points.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the screenshot, Birmingham has approximately 4HP left. This is because your rifleman will inflict approximately 4 dmg and then capture the city.

Comment: No sir, a city i am currently attacking has only 1 HP due to my artillery not being able to attack it further. My rifleman still says 3 DMG will be inflicted.

Comment: Touche. I should have said at most approx 4HP.

Comment: My question is: How many HP does the city have left. All we can do right now is estimate...

Comment: It may be the city is totally ruinned, and just waiting for you to send some infantry units in to capture it (artillery can't capture cities, iirc). But, as it's Birmingham... I'd say leave it their til you have nukes and deal with it that way.